# how to matching different numbers of features?

Tags: image, matching, feature-extraction, fingerprint, feature-selection

I'm working on a fingerprint matching program. The extracted features are minutiae, each of these features contains the location (x , y) and angle of direction (o).
The number of features extracted from images varies.

How can I match different numbers of features?

If I use the Euclidean distance, the vector of features must be equal in dimensions.

Comment: You want to develop your own matching software? Perhaps you'll get pointers from the source code of SourceAFIS: https://sourceafis.machinezoo.com/java. It implements a matching algorithm for fingerprints. There's a .NET version of the code, but I never looked at it.

Comment: Thank you so much.                                                                                                    I appreciate your help